# Jabber notifier plugin: There was an error sending notification to ***

Tags: plugins, jenkins, notifications, connection, xmpp

I just installed Jabber plugin for my Jenkins last week. 
I have a XMPP server running for quite a long time, and there is no connection problem
From Jenkins log, I got some error "Jabber notifier plugin: There was an error sending notification to.

But this error does not happen all the time, it just pop up sometimes and disappeared after a while. And I cannot see anything wrong from Jenkins' log.  and there is nothing generated after I created a system log for

```
hudson.plugins.jabber
```

as "FINEST" log level.

```
Nov 27, 2013 11:49:15 AM hudson.plugins.jabber.im.transport.JabberIMConnection
createConnection

INFO: Trying to connect to XMPP on <our_server>:5222/<our_server> with SASL

Nov 27, 2013 11:49:15 AM hudson.plugins.jabber.im.transport.JabberIMConnection
setupSubscriptionMode

INFO: Accepting all subscription requests

Nov 27, 2013 11:49:15 AM hudson.plugins.jabber.im.transport.JabberIMConnection connect
INFO: Connected to XMPP on <our_server>/<our_server> using TLS
```

Anyone knows if this is some stability issue with this plugin? Is there any way for me to do debug to see what exactly happened when this error pop up?

Thanks!